# Do I _have to_ use a pointer here?

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I've run into this problem time & again, and I've always had to resolve it using a forward declaration and a pointer.

It seems wrong that C++ *requires a work around* to get objects to co-operate.  Is there any way to get this to compile WITHOUT making Mesh* a pointer in class Shape (or, the `vector<Tri>` into `vector<Tri*>`?

### Shape.h

```
#ifndef S
#define S

#include "Mesh.h"
//class Mesh ; //delete line above, uncomment this to make it work
class Shape // a mathematical shape
{
    Mesh mesh ; // the poly mesh repr' this math shape
    //Mesh *mesh ; // make it work

    // a shape must be intersectable by a ray
    //virtual Intersection intersects( const Ray& ray )=0 ;
} ;

#endif
```

### Mesh.h

```
#ifndef M
#define M

#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include "Triangle.h"

struct Mesh
{
    vector<Triangle> tris ; // a mesh is a collection of triangles
} ;

#endif
```

### Triangle.h

```
#ifndef T
#define T
#include "Shape.h"
class Triangle : public Shape
{
    // a triangle must be intersectable by a ray
    // a triangle's mesh is simple but it is still a mesh (1 poly)
} ;
#endif
```

Comment: The compiler must know the size of all members of a class. Otherwise it cannot allocate the proper space for an object.

Comment: @Bo: `sizeof(vector<Triangle>)` doesn't necessarily depend on `sizeof(Triangle)`.

Comment: I don't get it.  You have a shape that owns a mesh that is composed of a list of triangles, which are shapes that each own a mesh that are composed of lists of triangles?

Comment: @Andre: That works if some of the lists are allowed to be empty, which doesn't appear to be the case with mesh/shape.

Comment: So, what you want is that every `Triangle`, via the `mesh` data member of its base class, contains a vector of `Triangle`. Presumably you intend this vector to have size 1, but what exactly does it contain? A Triangle, which has its own vector etc. Even if you break the circular dependency with a pointer, nowhere do you define the co-ordinates of the vertices. So the definition is still circular, and fails to actually define a triangle. The usual fix would be to not inherit Triangle from Shape - make `Triangle` three points, and a `Shape` with mesh size 1 just happens to be triangular.

Comment: @Ben - No, but if you have a `Shape` with a `Mesh` member, you need to know what a `Mesh` is. And if some crazy guy were to specialize `vector<Triangle>`, it *could* affect the size.

Comment: @Bo: If some crazy guy were to specialize `vector<Triangle>`, it wouldn't affect this code, because the template specialization isn't in scope.

Comment: Alternatively, you *could* add data members to `Triangle` for the points, change `Mesh` to contain a `vector<Triangle*>`, and in the triangle constructor do `tris.push_back(this);`. The C++ limitation here is that it's not possible for an object to be self-referential other than via a pointer or some such form of indirection. A `Triangle` instance can't be inside a vector that's inside the same `Triangle`. The same limitation applies to mathematical set theory, so anything that it renders impossible in C++ is also impossible in mathematics. What makes you special that you need it? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me without a pointer (there are, naturally, pointers used inside `std::vector`).  You just have to analyze your dependencies carefully.  `Triangle` inherits `Shape`, therefore `Shape`'s definition is above `Triangle`'s.  `Shape` contains a `Mesh`, therefore `Mesh`'s definition precedes `Shape`'s.  This gives the order: `Mesh, Shape, Triangle`, which [compiles without errors.](http://ideone.com/3bQJj)

Naturally, some meshes will have to have empty vectors, since every triangle inside the vector itself requires a mesh.

Answer (score 3):

You seem basically to be saying a Shape is implemented using a Mesh and a Mesh is implemented using shapes  (specifically triangles). This obviously doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Neil: I think he picked a bad example.  There are plenty of cases where such containment is appropriate, and eventually terminates with an empty collection of subobjects.

Comment: @Ben That makes even less sense to me than what the OP was doing.

Comment: @Neil: Think about a directory tree (on a filesystem where it really is a tree, hardlinks are not allowed).  Every node has a collection of child nodes.  Ultimately you have to reach leaf nodes where the child collection is empty.

Comment: @Ben Sorry, that does not float my boat. The OP's data structure is not  a tree, and a tree is made up of only one type - nodes.

Comment: @Neil: The OP's data structure is a tree (if you look only at the structure and ignore the names).  And a directory tree has both directories and files, two types of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

***You cannot declare a incomplete type as an member.***

When you forward declare a type, all the compiler know is that this type exists; it does not know anything about the size or members or methods. It's called an ***Incomplete type***

Unless you include `Mesh.h`, `Mesh` is a `Incomplete type` and you cannot declare incomplete type as a member.

But, You can have a pointer to `Incomplete type` as a member and so If you forward declare `class Mesh`, your member will have to be `Mesh*`

So in conclusion, what you have said is correct.

Comment: @bobobobo: Just finished editing that it can be a pointer and noticed your comment :)

Comment: This answer is true, but irrelevant.  `Mesh` does not have any member of type `Triangle`.

Comment: The vector of `Triangle` requires inclusion of the Triangle.h header

Answer (score 1):

You've always done it right and there's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your mesh in terms of a different, simple, low-level triangle struct. Your high-level Triangle "shape" can share collision code with the low level one while still being a separate class. Thus Mesh.h needn't include Triangle.h. This will break your cyclic dependency and let you have a Mesh member in the Shape class.

Comment: Its not a better design. `class Triangle1` and `class Triangle2`, with copied code? Definitely a kludge.