# Circular dependency assistance in C++

Tags: c++, include, visual-c++-2010-express

I have a code similar to the following one, but i cant get how to make it work.

I've searched for it and looks to be something about circular dependency, but for now, I've tried with some examples, but only work with a dependency of 2.

Instead, this one, I have the "Ctrl" classes that many classes are dependent of them (CtrlA and CtrlB are mutially dependent and Ax classes needs both Ctrl), but also the Ctrl files are needed of some of those clases (CtrlA needs Ax classes). Also, I have an inherited class (A2 inherits A3).

CtrlA.h

```
#ifndef CTRLA
#define CTRLA
#include "CtrlB.h"
#include "A1.h"

class CtrlB;
class A1;

class CtrlA{
    protected:
        A1 x;
    public:
        void op1(CtrlB b){
            a.op1(this, b);
        }
        void op2(){}
};
#endif
```

CtrlB.h

```
#ifndef CTRLB
#define CTRLB
#include "CtrlA.h"

class CtrlA;

class CtrlB{
    protected:
    public:
        void op1(){}
        void op2(CtrlA a){
            a.op1(this);
        }
};
#endif
```

A1.h

```
#ifndef A1
#define A1
#include "CtrlA.h"
#include "CtrlB.h"
#include "A2.h"

class CtrlA;
class CtrlB;

class A1{
    protected:
        A2 x1;
    public:
        void op1(CtrlA a, CtrlB b){
            x1.op1(this, b);
        }
};
#endif
```

A2.h

```
#ifndef A2
#define A2
#include "CtrlA.h"
#include "CtrlB.h"
#include "A3.h"

class CtrlA;
class CtrlB;

class A2:public A3{
    protected:

    public:
        void op1(CtrlA a, CtrlB b){
            a.op2();
            b.op1();
        }
};
#endif
```

A3.h

```
#ifndef A3
#define A3
#include "CtrlA.h"
#include "CtrlB.h"

class CtrlA;
class CtrlB;

class A3{
    protected:

    public:
        virtual void op1(CtrlA a, CtrlB b) = 0;
};
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "CtrlA.h"
#include "CtrlB.h"

int main(){
    int i;
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me to correct the code so it can work.

Comment: I am not sure why are you forward declaring the CtrlA and CtrlB classes in Ax classes. You already have them in CtrlA.h and CtrlB.h.

Comment: mmm Besides everything else I think 'a' is not declared in the scope of class CtrlA....but u kind of use it: void op1(CtrlB b){
            a.op1(this, b);
        }

Answer (score 1):

For CtrlA.h, CtrlB.h, A1.h, and A3.h you don't need to #include anything if you use forward declaration (which you sorta did) and use references or pointers (which you did not):

**CtrlA.h**

```
#ifndef CTRLA
#define CTRLA

class CtrlB;
class A1;

class CtrlA {
    protected:
        A1* x; 
    public:
        /* Use a CtrlB reference instead -- probably wanted to do this anyway  
        /* since you don't want to copy CtrlB when called */
        void op1(CtrlB& b); /* Move function body to .cpp file */
        void op2(){}
};
#endif
```

**A1.h**

```
#ifndef A1
#define A1

class CtrlA;
class CtrlB;
class A2; /* You have to use forward declaration on every class you use below */

class A1{
    protected:
        A2* x1;
    public:
        void op1(CtrlA& a, CtrlB& b); /* Again, use references and move function 
                                         bodies to .cpp */
};
#endif
```

But with A2.h, you're inheriting from A3, so you'll have to #include A3.h

**A2.h**

```
#ifndef A2
#define A2
#include "A3.h"

class CtrlA;
class CtrlB;

class A2:public A3{
    protected:

    public:
        void op1(CtrlA& a, CtrlB& b);
};
#endif
```

And that leaves main.cpp, where you'll want to include 'em all:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "CtrlA.h"
#include "CtrlB.h"
#include "A1.h"
#include "A2.h"
#include "A3.h"

int main(){
    int i;
}
```

Hope that helps! [Here is a quick reference](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml) to forward declaration and when/how to use it.

**Edit:** Thanks to Pablo for pointing out my error. You cannot use forward declared classes as member objects, only references or pointers. I've changed the above examples to use pointers.

Comment: You can't use forward declared classes as members. You can store *pointers* to forwarded classes, but not instances (e.g. member `x1` of class `A1`). Your solution doesn't compile in its current form.

Comment: so, the cpp files are like this?
#CtrlA.cpp
 #include "CtrlA.h"
 #include "CtrlB.h"
 #include "A1.h"

 void CtrlA::op1(CtrlB& b){
  x->op1(*this, b);
 }
#CtrlB.cpp
 #include "CtrlB.h"
 #include "CtrlA.h"
 
 void CtrlB::op2(CtrlA& a){
   a.op1(*this);
 }
#A1.cpp
 #include "A1.h"
 #include "A2.h"
 #include "CtrlA.h"
 #include "CtrlB.h"

 void A1::op1(CtrlA& a, CtrlB& b){
  x1->op1(&this, b);
 }
#A2.cpp
 #include "A2.h"
 #include "CtrlA.h"
 #include "CtrlB.h"

 void A2::op1(CtrlA& a, CtrlB& b){
  a.op2();
  b.op1();
 }
no A3.cpp
yet, this dont want to compile...
ugg doesnt appear as code...

Answer (score 0):

My advice: use more pointers and ***as many forward declarations as possible*** (and avoid #including other headers in .h files. #include them in the .cpp file where the implementation is needed.)

So

## CtrlA.h

```
#ifndef CTRLA
#define CTRLA
//#include "CtrlB.h"//no, don't #include this here, use fwd decl below
//#include "A1.h"   //no

class CtrlB; // yes, use forward decl ONLY as much as possible
class A1;    // yes

// the only reason you'd NEED to have an #include is
// if CtrlA INHERITED CtrlB. Then you'd need to #include "CtrlB.h"

class CtrlA{
    protected:
        A1 *x; // make PTR, meaning you can live off
               // the fwd declaration in the header file
               // (but will need to #include "A1.h" in
               //  the .cpp file to use member functions of A1)
    public:
        void op1(CtrlB *b) ; // CtrlB ptr, NO IMPLEMENTATION HERE, put in .cpp
        void op2() ; // no impl
};
#endif
```

[You cannot declare a incomplete type as an member.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6317334/111307)

The bit of useful information you'll find in the 2nd answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317309/do-i-have-to-use-a-pointer-here)